# How to set Get-ADComputer result as object

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have this Powershell command:

```
Get-ADComputer -filter { Name -like 'srv*' } | Select -Expand dnshostname | Export-CSV -path ad_export.csv
```

In the CSV it only writes the length of the Strings. I read that I have to pipe an object to Export-CSV so it writes the Servernames and not only the length. How do I do that?

Comment: Can you please post an example of what your output csv looks like? I tried verifying your command and got a csv as a result that contains the DistinguishedName, DNSHostName, etc., all with proper values.

Comment: It's just a long list of the number 22 from top to bottom (the length of each servername). Does that mean the problem could be in our ad?

Comment: Try first to run only `Get-ADComputer -filter { Name -like 'srv*' } | Select -Expand dnshostname` and verify that the output looks as it should.

Comment: It does. The output in Powershell the servernames which I need in my excel

Comment: Remove the `-Expand` in the select statement if you want a single column csv with the `DNSHostName` attribute values

Comment: Thanks, I guess that was the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the requirement , you can use :

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'ObjectClass -eq "Computer"' | Select -Expand DNSHostName | Export-CSV -path ad_export.csv

# Getting just the hostname

Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Select -Expand Name |  Export-CSV -path ad_export.csv

# Getting a specific computer 

Get-ADComputer -Filter { Name -eq 'server2012' } -Propert LastLogonTimestamp | Select DistinguishedName, LastLogonTimestamp | Format-Table -AutoSize |  Export-CSV -path ad_export.csv
```

*Note:* You can use the "where" clause also if required.
Hope This suffice your need